# Cannot assign a value to final variable 'weekTotalDaylyMinutes'

Tags: java, arrays

I have list of Overtime entities, I need to filter them, after I need to get array of dailyReports of each of them and calculate weekTotalDaylyMinutes variable.

```
final long weekTotalDaylyMinutes = 0;

List<Overtime> all;
            all = this.shiftRepository
                    .findAllOvertimesByYearAndMonth(year, month)
                    .stream()
                    .filter(o -> this.getOvertimeWeekOfYear(o) == currentOvertimeWeekOfYear
                            && o.getDeleted() == false
                            && !Objects.equals(o.getId(), genericOvertimeDTO.getId()))
                    .peek(overtime->this.getDialyOvertimeReports(overtime, year, month)
                            .stream()
                            .peek(a-> weekTotalDaylyMinutes+=a.getDayMinutes())
                    )
```

But I got the error:
`Cannot assign a value to final variable 'weekTotalDaylyMinutes'!`
How to solve the issue ? I need to get summ of all a.getDayMinutes of all overtimes in this variable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `final` means you cannot change it anymore. Its value is `final`.

Comment: Aside from the actual problem, this is abusing the stream API. Use sum(). Also, weekTotalDaylyMinutes is poorly named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array with one element to allow modification in the lambda.

```
final long[] weekTotalDaylyMinutes = {0};

List<Overtime> all;
            all = this.shiftRepository
                    .findAllOvertimesByYearAndMonth(year, month)
                    .stream()
                    .filter(o -> this.getOvertimeWeekOfYear(o) == currentOvertimeWeekOfYear
                            && o.getDeleted() == false
                            && !Objects.equals(o.getId(), genericOvertimeDTO.getId()))
                    .peek(overtime->this.getDialyOvertimeReports(overtime, year, month)
                            .stream()
                            .peek(a-> weekTotalDaylyMinutes[0] +=a.getDayMinutes())
                    );
System.out.println(weekTotalDaylyMinutes[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Final variables cannot be modified. Also since your are suing lambda functions , the variable should effectively final.

So you have to keep the count inside some object.

Create a  class  with one value and keep the weekTotalDaylyMinutes inside that,

Answer (score 0):

A final value is one you wouldnt like to change anytime soon, a constant value like.
So if you really want to use weekTotalDailyMinutes, I suggest you remove the 'final' keyword or better yet use 'static' if you're looking for a variable that transcends instances of a class